# Disable ECB menu in SPGridview

Tags: sharepoint-2007, spgridview

I need to disable OOtb Filtering and Sorting menu in SPGridview and apply custom filtering and  sorting. So far i have done custom part and it comnfuses with ootb filtering when user tried to use both. so suggest me a way to disable ootb filtering and sorting in spgridview

Comment: Since no one answered this question i found the answer below.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling ECB menu in SPgridview is bit tricky and using jquery would be ideal to do that.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ms-unselectedtitle').removeAttr("onclick");
        $('.ms-unselectedtitle').removeAttr("onmouseover");
        $('.ms-menuimagecell').remove();
      }); 
    </script>
```

simply it will remove the onclick and onmousover attribute as well as remove the arrow image from spgridview header..